# MySQL inconsistent date ordering

Tags: mysql, hibernate, grails

I've encountered a curious problem while debugging a failing integration test. I seem to get inconsistent results depending on the sort direction (`ASC` / `DESC`) of the following query:

```
SELECT u.id, u.last_updated FROM user u WHERE u.id IN (36, 37, 38, 39, 40) ORDER BY u.last_updated ASC;
```

The above query returns these results, which is as I would expect:

```
id  last_updated
=======================
36  2015-07-15 19:45:34
37  2015-07-15 19:45:34
38  2015-07-15 19:45:34
39  2015-07-15 19:45:35
40  2015-07-15 19:45:35
```

However, if I switch the sort order from `ASC` to `DESC`, I get this:

```
id  last_updated
=======================
39  2015-07-15 19:45:35
40  2015-07-15 19:45:35
36  2015-07-15 19:45:34
37  2015-07-15 19:45:34
38  2015-07-15 19:45:34
```

It's as if MySQL is unable to distinguish the difference between the dates with more than second accuracy when the query is in descending order.

If I change the dates so that there is a 1 second gap between each `last_updated` value, then the ordering works correctly in both directions.

These queries are being executed via a Grails / Hibernate based application. If I add some debug code in my application, I can see that the dates are all different and accurate to 1 ms:

```
1436989535410, 1436989535646, 1436989534516, 1436989534990, 1436989534751
```

So the data is being stored to a sufficient precision...

User table declaration looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `last_updated` datetime NOT NULL,
  ...
)
```

I'm using MySQL 5.6.15.

The same query / integration test works correctly when tested with the H2 Java in-memory database.

**EDIT:**

Interestingly, it does look like some precision is being lost. If I run the following query:

```
SELECT u.id, u.last_updated, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(u.last_updated) FROM user u WHERE u.id IN (36, 37, 38, 39, 40) ORDER BY u.last_updated ASC;
```

I get this:

```
id  last_updated         unix timestamp
=======================================
36  2015-07-15 19:45:34  1436985934
37  2015-07-15 19:45:34  1436985934
38  2015-07-15 19:45:34  1436985934
39  2015-07-15 19:45:35  1436985935
40  2015-07-15 19:45:35  1436985935
```

I guess Hibernate is caching the more precise pre-persistence date values and giving them back to me when I try to debug in my application...

Comment: Timestamp its the number of seconds since 1970,it doesnt hold miliseconds

Comment: to add to @Mihai remark: So your ascending ID in the ascending sort is just coincedence.

Comment: Apologies - timestamp was the wrong word. The dates are persisted as MySQL `datetime`s

Comment: A DATETIME or TIMESTAMP value can include a trailing fractional seconds part in up to microseconds (6 digits) precision. Although this fractional part is recognized, it is discarded from values stored  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html

Comment: In my application tier, I can see that the values have been persisted to (at least) millisecond precision. It should be possible for MySQL to order them correctly...

Comment: Mysql does stores the miliseconds on version >=5.6.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change the `last_updated` field to `DATETIME(6)` instead of `DATETIME`. This way you can get microsecond resolution. [MySQL Reference.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fractional-seconds.html)

Answer (score 0):

You might add the `id` field as denominator of equal seconds as inserts are atomar (first come fist serve)

```
 ... 40) ORDER BY u.last_updated ASC, id ASC;
```

resp.

```
 ... 40) ORDER BY u.last_updated DESC, id DESC;
```

[SQL fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b285d/3)